# How can I integrate a video conferencing solution using google+ hangout api?

Tags: google-hangouts

How can I integrate google+ hangout inside my webapp? Can I have hangout as part of my webapp? It seems that our application is a part or an extension of google+.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you're concerned about the branding/business aspect, and not the technical aspect.  If you want the video chat capability in your application but done in a way where your users will not be flown into the Google+ world and workflows, there are plenty of other videoconferencing APIs you can use.  I have evaluated all of these thoroughly within the past year:

- [Vidyo](http://www.vidyo.com) - uses Scalable Video Codec, best quality videoconference, hands down
- [VSee](http://www.vsee.com) - proprietary algorithm offers best compression over the wire for lowest bandwidth requirements
- [OpenTok](http://www.opentok.com) - good use of WebRTC on supported browsers; struggled on mobile devices and IE/Safari
- [SecureVideo](http://www.securevideo.com/Features#API) - uses VSee technology, but at much lower cost with some added scheduling/HIPAA/workflow features (disclaimer: this is my company)
- [AVSpeed](http://avspeed.com) - this is a pure SDK, and very inexpensive--the video performance was poor when we evaluated it, but could be the right choice if you just need branded video but aren't too particular about the quality

Hope this helps!

Comment: Vidyo carries a $1500 license fee for a single concurrent connection, along with an $8500 1u router that handles up to 100 concurrent connections. In other words, it's very expensive.

Comment: fyi the avspeed sdk now uses webrtc  https://avspeed.com/

Comment: Zoom now tests out as the best videoconferencing quality over Vidyo. It is 2018, and Vidyo and Zoom are still much, much more reliable than WebRTC. My company, SecureVideo, switched from VSee to Zoom as our primary engine in 2016. We're waiting for WebRTC to come along further and then we will integrate that, but we still get dozens of customers per month migrating to us *from* WebRTC due to quality issues... :/